# Material-ui Autucomplete: specifying custom CloseIconButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

folks

So my issue is simple. I want to provide custom closeIconButton. And only closeIcon prop is available. 
CloseIcon prop doesn't suffice because I need this custom button to have onClick property.
And if I place onClick on CloseIcon material-ui will warn: `Failed prop type: Material-UI: you are providing an onClick event listener to a child of a button element.
Firefox will never trigger the event.`

```
<Autocomplete
     open={open}
     classes={classes}
     options={practicesList}
     getOptionLabel={get('name')}
     value={curPractice}
     blurOnSelect
     closeIcon={<CloseIcon onClick={() => onChange(null)} />}
     onChange={async (e, option) => {
       if (!option) return

       onChange(option.id)
     }}
     renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} autoFocus={autoFocus} fullWidth label={label} margin="none" />}
     renderOption={(practice, { inputValue }) => {
       const matches = match(practice.name, inputValue)
       const letters = parse(practice.name, matches)

       return (
         <div>
           {letters.map((letter, i) => (
             <span key={i} style={{ fontWeight: letter.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}>
               {letter.text}
             </span>
           ))}
         </div>
       )
     }}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

From [api docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) `closeIcon` should be just some node. For example:

```
<CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
```

Than, you can use `onClose` prop directly on `Autocomplete` component to specify some callback. Hope this helps.